# Which nouns can use 美化語{びかご}?

Tags: nouns, honorifics, bikago

- Whether a noun is [サ変名詞]{さへんめいし}, or not, is an attribute that is specified in the dictionary definition of nouns.
- "Possible to use 美化語{びかご}" surely should be an attribute of a noun? But, I do not see this attribute specified in dictionary definitions.

Is there a list of the nouns that can possibly use 美化語?
If not, you just have to use "feel" for where to use 美化語?
Is it grammatically wrong to place 美化語 where it should not be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [small list](http://keigo.livedoor.biz/archives/787951.html) that I found through a quick search online--I'm sure there's more.

In the box on this [website](http://www.levelup99.net/businessmanner/cate3post25.html) there is another list and it also mentions that when using 美化語{びかご} you should be careful of sounding unnatural or 'not-good' if you try to add the お or ご to words that do not require it.

In my experience, I have been told that it's just a memorization thing, and you shouldn't try to just put it on any word that you think should have it.  I've also been told that it sounds 'less beautiful' if you use it on the wrong words.