# ご・おXXXいただく（？） vs ご・おXXXください

Tags: grammar, keigo

I know that ください one is nicely phrased command, like ご注意ください。Is there similar construction with いただく、how is it formed and what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually three things you need to keep track of to answer your question.

1. くださる expresses that someone above you is doing something for you. If they were closer to the same level you would use くれる. 　Thus, くださる is the 敬語 of くれる. The less polite form is やる.
2. いただく expresses that the speaker is *receiving* what someone else does for them. It is the 敬語 of もらう.
3. ご・お are called 美化語 and serve to make crude things more polite or to express respect for the one who does that thing. See [which nouns can use 美化語{びかご}?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13654/which-nouns-can-use-%E7%BE%8E%E5%8C%96%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%B3%E3%81%8B%E3%81%94) .

Thus, combinations of 1 + 3 and  2 + 3 are both possible because 1 expresses that someone politely does something for you whereas 2 expresses that you politely receive something.

ご心配いただきありがとうございます。 = 2 + 3. The 心配 is marked by ご because you're showing respect for the person who does it. いただく then shows that you are receiving it subordinately.

お電話ください =1 + 3 = the person you're speaking to does the 電話する so we make it a polite command by using both the 美化語 and the ください construction.

Also, while everyone recognizes the 漢字 for both 下さる and 頂く, in contemporary Japanese, the government indicates you should use hiragana in this sort of helping verb usage (https://docoic.com/714).

For more information on the split, you can look at:

- [Differences between くれます, もらいます and いただきます](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/260/differences-between-%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99-%E3%82%82%E3%82%89%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99-and-%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%8D%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99)
- https://www.alc.co.jp/jpn/article/faq/05/141.html
- http://web.ydu.edu.tw/~uchiyama/1h93fy/jyujyu.html

Answer (score 1):

The difference here is between polite and humble Japanese.

ご～ください is an honorific phrase, used to be very polite when asking other people to do something. いただく is a humble verb, usually used when referring to yourself or someone in your group. So there is no equivalent verbal phrase like ご～いただく. I recommend reading some of the threads about honorific vs humble Japanese. This will help to clarify what type of phrase to use in various kinds of situations.

Answer (score 1):

下さる/頂くexpress give/receive a favor to/from a higher status entity.
Both verbs are used with 御（ご、お）as explained in the following links:

https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/61762/meaning/m0u/

https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/12108/meaning/m0u/

Examples from https://tatoeba.org

お手伝いいただきありがとう。Thank you for your assistance.

ご検討頂くために。For your consideration.